# Best way to cast from unsigned to signed while mapping the minimal and maximal?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

Does anyone know a smart C++ or C trick to cast `uint16_t` to `int16_t` while also mapping from `[0; 65535]` to `[−32768; 32767]`?

I tried `static_cast<std::int16_t>(value - std::numeric_limits<std::int16_t>::lowest())`, but I'm not sure if that is the optimal solution.
So what is the best way?

While this question is mostly focused on C++11, C answers are welcome too.

Comment: Looks like a reasonable way to me.  Depending on what you need the signed version to represent.  Some platforms, the lowest will be `-32767`.

Comment: you are not clear, what do you expect if the initial values is 32768 ?

Comment: Just to clarify, for instance you want `uint16_t x = 0` to be converted to `-32768` of a `int16_t` type?

Comment: This is not casting. In a cast, the same underlying data is considered to be a different type. You will have to subtract 32768 as part of your conversion, and ... maybe it will wrap and work out if that's all you do, I'd have to test it before I post that as an answer. But it sounds risky because c++ doesn't usually enforce signed/unsigned mismatches as strictly as other data types.

Comment: @Fureeish Yes. That is exactly what I want.

Comment: @bruno I expect 0 or 1 as the result.

Comment: The behaviour of the cast is *implementation-defined* but should work in practice on any common 2's complement platform.

Comment: `static_cast<std::int16_t>(value-std::numeric_limits<std::int16_t>::lowest())` I'm afraid I can't read this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to map `[0 .. 65535]` to `[-32768 .. 32767]`, no magic c++ incantation is needed: just substract `32768`. If your platform has 32-bit ints, the integer promotions will make the expression below fully defined:

```
uint16_t uv = <some value>;
int16_t sv = uv - 32768;
```

If type `int32_t` is available, you can write:

```
uint16_t uv = <some value>;
int16_t sv = (int32_t)uv - 32768;
```

but the first version is fully defined also on platforms with 16-bit ints because `32768` would have type `long` there and `uv` would be converted to type `long` preserving its value. The result is in range for type `int16_t` by definition, so no problem.